# publish code only to Azure, without updating data

Tags: asp.net, azure, web-deployment

My Asp.net project uses an SQL db. I need to update the published version on Azure. It keeps failing on the db deploy. The thing is, all I need to update is the code. The current data are fine. Is there a way to tell it to go ahead and deploy the code and leave the data unchanged?

Comment: Needs a lot more information than you've provided. Are you using code first, a separate db project, data migrations. What is your project layout, how is it publishing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Under project settings, package/publish SQL, remove the database.